# Aggregating mysql data on hourly basis

Tags: c#, mysql

I  have data whose creation time is stored in UTC format. Now I want to aggregate this data on hourly basis and display it according to IST.

If I add 5:30 hours to utc time i will IST but the problem is it will be like 5:30, 6:30 , 7:30 .... but I want it 5, 6, 7, 8...no half hour count.

How to go about it.

Comment: Difficult to assume lot of things, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on transformation. If creation time is 04:07 UTC then it is 09:37 IST. Full stop. IST is a half-hour time zone.

You will have to aggregate the data by hour AFTER transformation.

Regards